# How to convert std::string to QString preserving values and vice versa?

Tags: c++, string, qt, c++11

I am dealing with std::strings, in low level processing so I have to manipulate bits of characters of that string.

Also I have to show the results using GUI by viewing the result on QPlainTextEdit, as they may be copied for reverse processing.
so I deal with strings and results like 0xe3 may occur. and when I convert the std::string to QString to be shown in the GUI and vice versa. I use,

```
 QString::fromStdString(myString); // to convert std::string to QString
 myQString.toStdString();          // to convert back from QString to std::string
```

The problem is that when values result from processing on the string. after converting it to QString and try to
convert it back, values change.
I mean the value of each character,for example

> 0x3f becomes 0xbd, and 0xe3 becomes 0xef

I guess the problem happens due to encoding issues between std::string and QString, but I can not figure out how to deal with it or how to get the right values from QString.

Comment: If you read the [`QString` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html), the `std::string` that you pass to `QString::fromStdString()` must be in UTF-8 format, and `QString::toStdString()` returns a `std::string` that is in UTF-8 format.

Comment: `QString` holds Unicode characters in UTF-16 format, where converting from `std::string` to `QString` involves a UTF8->UTF16 conversion, and converting from `QString` to `std::string` involves a UTF16->UTF8 conversion. Such conversions are lossless, but may not be what you are expecting if you are not prepared to deal with `std::string` in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Sounds like you want to be converting to/from `QByteArray`, not `QString`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I got it.
but I mainly care about preserving their values so I could get them back represented in 8-bit char type, i.e. I want to get back 0xe3 and other non-ASCII values from QString.
also I have to present these meaningless characters so anybody could copy them and when presented again to the program. It should recognize the values again.
even if there is some intermediate stage that would be fine.

Comment: @Ammar: Conversions between UTFs are lossless. If you are losing data, it means you are not converting data correctly to begin with.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem in action. For instance, `0xE3` is not a valid char by itself in a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`. If you have Unicode char `U+00E3` (`LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE`), it is encoded as `0xC3 0xA3` in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The source string is not valid UTF-8 and thus the roundtrip fails because the `toStdString` and `fromStdString` methods assume UTF-8. The Latin-1 roundtrip shouldn't fail and should simply map bytes 0-255 to Unicode C0 and C1. The code is a bit more verbose:

```
void test(const std::string & input) {
  auto latin_input = QByteArray::fromStdString(input);
  auto string = QString::fromLatin1(latin_input);
  auto latin_output = string.toLatin1();
  Q_ASSERT(latin_input == latin_output);
  auto output = latin_output.toStdString();
  Q_ASSERT(input == output);
}
```

Note that many of the Latin-1 characters are not printable, so the `QPlainTextEdit` will not display them! To fix that, you'd need to create a custom translation table that provides a printable equivalent for every character code between 0 and 255.